# Assign values to df using another df in a different format

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
d = {'year': [1990, 1991], 'org': ['EU', 'EU'], 'UK': [1, 1], 'Croatia': [-9, 1], 'Germany': [1,1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df1

    year    org UK  Croatia Germany
0   1990    EU  1    -9       1
1   1991    EU  1     1       1


d = {'year': [1990, 1991], 'country1': ['Israel', 'EU'], 'country2': ['EU', 'Brzail']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2

    year    country1    country2
0   1990     Israel        EU 
1   1991     EU         Brzail
```

I want to change EU in df2 with countries that have 1 in df1.
The result should like this:

```
    year    country1                country2
0   1990     Israel                 UK, Germany   
1   1991     UK, Germany, Croatia   Brzail
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i apologize for the messy solution but that's the best i could come up with.

```
df3 = df1.melt(id_vars = ['year', 'org'])
df3 = df3[df3['value'] == 1]
df3 = df3.groupby(['year', 'org'])['variable'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
df2 = pd.merge(df2, df3, on = 'year', how = 'left')
df2.loc[df2['country1'] == 'EU', 'country1'] = df2['variable']
df2.loc[df2['country2'] == 'EU', 'country2'] = df2['variable']
df2 = df2[['year', 'country1', 'country2']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `dot` then `merge`

```
s = df1.loc[:,'UK':]
s.eq(1).dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1]
df1['New'] = s.eq(1).dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1]
df2 = df2.merge(df1[['year','New']])
newdf2 = df2.mask(df2=='EU',df2.New,axis=0).drop('New',1)
newdf2
Out[249]: 
   year            country1    country2
0  1990              Israel  UK,Germany
1  1991  UK,Croatia,Germany      Brzail
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i am writing a custom function to get the list of positions of the keyword (i.e. "EU" in your case).

First we will find out all the countries in a particular column index with 1's. I will get an array.

Once i get all the positions (row_value,column_name), i am using the information data_frame[column_name][row_value] and replace it with arrays index.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'year': [1990, 1991], 'org': ['EU', 'EU'], 'UK': [1, 1], 'Croatia': [-9, 1], 'Germany': [1,1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


d = {'year': [1990, 1991], 'country1': ['Israel', 'EU'], 'country2': ['EU', 'Brzail']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# print(df1)
# print(df2)

country_names_with_one = df1.apply(lambda row: row[row == 1].index, axis=1)




def getIndexes(dfObj, value):
    # Empty list
    listOfPos = []

    # isin() method will return a dataframe with
    # boolean values, True at the positions
    # where element exists
    result = dfObj.isin([value])

    # any() method will return
    # a boolean series
    seriesObj = result.any()

    # Get list of column names where
    # element exists
    columnNames = list(seriesObj[seriesObj == True].index)

    # Iterate over the list of columns and
    # extract the row index where element exists
    for col in columnNames:
        rows = list(result[col][result[col] == True].index)

        for row in rows:
            listOfPos.append((row, col))

            # This list contains a list tuples with
    # the index of element in the dataframe
    return listOfPos


# Calling getIndexes() function to get
# the index positions of all occurrences
# of EU in the dataframe-2
listOfPositions = getIndexes(df2, "EU")


for i in range(len(listOfPositions)):
    col_name = listOfPositions[i][1] #Column names of the listof positions
    row_val = listOfPositions[i][0] #Row values of the listof positions

    df2[col_name][row_val] = ",".join(str(x) for x in country_names_with_one[row_val].array) #df2[col][row] gives me "EU" which i am replacing using the coountry names with flag 1

print(df2)
```